# Develop and deploy RESTful web service

Tags: web-services, rest, jax-rs, netbeans-7, glassfish-4

I followed [Creating a RESTful Web Service Using NetBeans IDE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/giqaa/index.html). I implemented all the steps from step no 1 to 6 successfully and able to test my REST web service on my machine.

But now I want to **deploy** my web service for **stand alone Glassfish v4** server and want to **access** from another machine or node **from the local network**.

I **deployed the .War** file on stand alone Glassfish v4 from the front-end of Glassfish but it is **not accessible** from other node of the network. The **View Endpoint** option is not coming after deployment.

Please guide me what steps should i follow, what is missing or suggest me how to deploy .war on glassfish v4.

Answer (score 0):

- Look into the log messages of the stand alone GF.
- Check proxy settings and other connection settings